# I have several functions that do the same thing. How do I put it all in one function?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("isfine").addEventListener('click', showMe);

function showMe(e){
  let x = document.getElementById('crying')

  if(x.style.display == 'none'){
    x.style.display = 'block'
  } else{
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.getElementById("mine").addEventListener('click', showMe2);

function showMe2(e){
  let x = document.getElementById('heroes')

  if(x.style.display == 'none'){
    x.style.display = 'block'
  } else{
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I tried passing arguments into my function, but then I did not know what to do with the expressions that are not in the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `showMe` and pass in the id of the target element you wish to target - this would refactor the use of creating new functions for the same functionality

such that

```
function showMe(e, target) {
  // find target
}
```

---

```js
document.getElementById("isfine").addEventListener('click', e => showMe(e, "crying"));
document.getElementById("mine").addEventListener('click', e => showMe(e, "heroes"));

function showMe(e, target) {

  let x = document.getElementById(target);
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  e.preventDefault();  
}
```

```html
<button id="isfine">isfine</button>
<button id="mine">mine</button>

<div id="crying">crying</div>
<div id="heroes">heroes</div>
```

Comment: I will. Quick question though. When I click the target again, the content disappears. It is fine in this instance, but why doesn't it stay?

Comment: the style `display` turns to none - hence hiding the content - check the snippet above

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to get things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), focus on identifying only what differs between logic blocks. You then replace the constants with variables which values are provided through function arguments.

e.g.

```js
initToggler('trigger1', 'trigger1Content');
initToggler('trigger2', 'trigger2Content');
  
function initToggler(triggerId, contentId) {
  const contentEl = document.getElementById(contentId);
  document.getElementById(triggerId).addEventListener('click', togglerFor(contentEl));
}

function togglerFor(el) {
  return () => el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none'? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<button id="trigger1">Toggle Content 1</button>
<button id="trigger2">Toggle Content 2</button>

<div id="trigger1Content">trigger1 content</div>
<div id="trigger2Content">trigger2 content</div>
```

Here we've made progress by eliminating some duplicate logic, but we could do more. HTML tells you a lot about the document's structure, but it can also tell you about it's behaviors by using declarative markup. At first glance it may seem like a lot of extra code, but we've now extended the HTML with a new `data-toggle` attribute and the HTML became a little more behavior-telling.

e.g.

```js
initTogglers();

function initTogglers() {
  Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]')).forEach(el => {
    initToggler(el, el.dataset.toggle);
  });
}
  
function initToggler(triggerEl, contentId) {
  const contentEl = document.getElementById(contentId);
  triggerEl.addEventListener('click', togglerFor(contentEl));
}

function togglerFor(el) {
  return () => el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none'? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<button data-toggle="content1">Toggle Content 1</button>
<button data-toggle="content2">Toggle Content 2</button>

<div id="content1">trigger1 content</div>
<div id="content2">trigger2 content</div>
```

If you continue down that path, you'll eventually arrive to the concept of domain-specific HTML where you'd have your own elements and attributes. That's basically how most web UIs are built these days, using reusable components, most often on the foundation of various librairies such as React or Angular.

I'm fully aware my answer goes way beyond the question, but I thought it would be a good learning opportunity and that's still all very related to avoiding code duplication.